# How do fadeout/in and Slideleft/SlideRight animation simultaneously

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to slidein and Fadeout animation navigation on the same time,while navigating to next page.

For fading out,I am using below Code.

```
    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layoutanim, "alpha",
            1f, .3f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(5000);
```

For Sliding,I got code using animation

```
public Animation inFromRightAnimation() {

    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    inFromRight.setDuration(500);
    inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromRight;
}
```

I am trying to play together using animator set.But it is using animation for slidein effect.How to convert  inFromRightAnimation() from animation to animator to play it together.Or else is there any way to acheive inFromRight using Object Animator.

Comment: use it. https://github.com/jendib/BlurActionBarDrawerToggle  it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html)

```
Animation fade = new AlphaAnimation(1f, .3f);
fade.setDuration(5000);
Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
inFromRight.setDuration(500);
inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
animationSet.addAnimation(inFromRight);
animationSet.addAnimation(fade);
layoutanim.setAnimation(animationSet);
```